# How to make a exe file from python ML project?

Tags: python, windows, computer-vision, python-packaging

I want to make a windows application from my python project. Since it is a machine learning project, lot of dependencies  are there.  How to convert the ML Project into a executable file.

Comment: Can you specify the types of content and/or dependencies in the application ?

Answer (score 0):

[py2exe](https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/), or [cx-Freeze](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Freeze/) or other libraries for building windows apps usually figure the dependencies on their own. Also, you can have a config where you can specify any extra details, files, and dependencies included.

You may also need some kind of GUI for a windows app

Answer (score 0):

I can highly recommend `pyinstaller`, it will include all necessary dependencies and is rather easy to use and well documented. I suggest you give it a try